# 2 SELECT with INTERSECT or 2 condition with WHERE

Tags: sql

I have a task that **"Get the makers producing both PCs having a speed of 750 MHz or higher and laptops with a speed of 750 MHz or higher.
Result set: maker"** from https://www.sql-ex.ru

For this task I wrote this query which is return nothing (empty screen)

```
SELECT MAKER FROM PRODUCT P
INNER JOIN PC ON PC.MODEL=P.MODEL
INNER JOIN LAPTOP L ON L.MODEL=P.MODEL
WHERE PC.SPEED>=750 AND L.SPEED>=750
```

But the right query is

```
select product.maker from product
inner join pc
on product.model = pc.model   
where pc.speed >= 750

intersect

select product.maker 
from product 
inner join laptop
on product.model = laptop.model
where laptop.speed >= 750
```

I wonder what is the differences between these two queries and why my query doesn't get the true output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version requires that the same product have both characteristics.  This is probably not possible -- because the same model would need to be both a PC and a laptop.

The `intersect` version allows the characteristics to be on *different* products.

Comment: So, if I have  2 joins in a select statement. These joined tables' must have same characteristics to use in a WHERE clause? Am I right?

Comment: @İrfanÇalışır . . . Look at the `JOIN` conditions.  They are saying that `MODEL` is the same in all three tables -- something that probably cannot happen.